# Why can't I get Cassandra to work with Cloudflare DNS (timing out)

Tags: cassandra, cloudflare

I have a site that points at a running at home. A Home Assistant instance runs on port 443 so I can check that to make sure everything on the server is running. When I try to hit my external IP everything connects fine but when I change to the domain I get a failure

```
DBMS: Cassandra (ver. 4.1.3)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=exact
Driver: Cassandra JDBC Driver (ver. 1.4, JDBC4.2)
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: domain/ip:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [domain/ip] Cannot connect))
connection timed out: domain/ip:9042.
```

Also the ip is incorrect (different than the external ip in the a record) so I am confused DNS is through Cloudflare.

How do I get Cassandra to work through a domain?